# How to get SVN revision number and then pass to android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, svn

I am trying to follow the article below:

http://ballardhack.wordpress.com/2010/09/28/subversion-revision-in-android-app-version-with-eclipse/

But I am lost to the description below:

> Save this to .externalToolBuilders/AddSvnRevisionToVersion.launch
>   (this folder, relative to the root of your project space, is the
>   default location that Eclipse stores this kind of stuff; if you are
>   adding this to more than one project, then name it using a
>   fully-qualified name, like com.example.AddSvnRevisionToVersion.launch,
>   because Eclipse makes these names global)

Obviously I couldn't create a folder with "." as folder name. Then what actually does the description above mean?

Beside that, anyone has better and simpler way to grasp SVN revision number when we build android app by using eclipse? I am a IDE user, so build the app with command line is quite tough for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this folder already exists. It's preceded by a '.' meaning it's probably hidden.

Try making your hidden files visible (instructions will vary depending on your OS) and searching for it.

Comment: I have double checked, there is no such file in the project folder. How come?

Comment: If it's not there then create it. Use the command line for this since naming a file with a preceding '.' may not be allowed by your GUI

Comment: Thank, I will try later. It also mention to add "fully-qualified name" in front of the folder name, do you know is it necessary? And it says eclipse make these names global?

Comment: If your are adding it to more than one project then you should think about doing it. Otherwise it should be fine.